# Deleting Vendor Credits in Suitescript?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Hi all i am trying to use record.delete on a vendor credit. below is the code i am using, and i am quite sure the type is correct

```
var record = require('N/record')
try{
      record.delete({
      type:record.Type.VENDOR_CREDIT,
      id: 10422429
    })
}catch(e){
log.debug('e',e)
}
```

can someone help me see where i am going wrong ? I am sure the type is correct from the records browser, and it is not a custom record. i have attempted this in debugger and in sandbox with the same error:

> "type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INVALID_TRANS_TYP","message":"Transaction
> type specified is incorrect."

Comment: So, what's the value of `record.Type.VENDOR_CREDIT` then?

Comment: that is the type of record... https://3751499-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273205732.html
this lists the enum types

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your first line is correct I tried to run it on the debugger and it shows some errors.

Anyway you can use this sample to delete record using SS2.0

```
require(['N/record'],
    /**
     * @param {record} record
     */
    function(record) {
try{
      record.delete({
      type: record.Type.VENDOR_CREDIT,
      id: 10422429//record Id
    });
}catch(e){
log.debug('e',e)
}



});
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad that is exactly the code that i have, ignoring the require line which i have for my debugger. did that code work for you ? it gave me the error i posted in the original thread please see

Comment: Yes, I tried it, you can use my previous code in the debugger it should work.

I checked your code you should know that the require takes two arguments the module dependencies and a call back function the function called when the dependencies are loaded as you can see in my code sample but since you just call the require then use it directly the dependencies are not loaded yet that's why.

Comment: Note: when using a debugger you can wait after running the required line don't run the record.delete too fast if you wait for it enough the module will be loaded and you won't have that error. Also, you should always use the require with a callback function.